# Leap year program doing wrong things for a specific input

Tags: python, windows, function, if-statement, leap-year

So I got this question from my friend yesterday regarding a program to check if a year is leap or not using python and decided to help. I wrote it up and it seems to run just fine until I enter 1992 as an input in which case it returns false (which shouldn't be the case). So I'm wondering where I wrong.

My code :
`

```
def is_leap(year):
   leap = False

   if (year % 4) == 0:
       if (year % 100) == 0:
           if (year % 400) == 0:
               leap = True
           else:
               leap = False
       else:
           leap = False
   else:
       leap = False

   return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Results :
1992 - > False

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with your code: first of all I would do checks in a partially reverse order, e.g.

1. start checking year % 400,
2. then in your line 5 you have a logical error: it has to be

   if not (year % 100) == 0:
3. only then check for year % 4

The code can look like:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if (year % 400) == 0:
        leap = True
    elif ((year % 100) != 0 and (year % 4) == 0):
        leap = True
    else:
        leap = False
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the nested `if` statements. Leapyears are either `year % 100 != 0 and year % 4 == 0` **or** `year % 400 == 0`.

Try this:

```py
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if year % 100 != 0 and year % 4 == 0 or year % 400 == 0:
        leap = True 

    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```